# Cycles 2.71 Smoke Rendered On Wrong Frame(s)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to make an explosion for the first time. To prepare, I made a sphere and used `Quick Explode` and `Quick Smoke` on it. After a lot of fiddling, I rendered my final animation. My problem is that, instead of exploding at frame 50, it would render the explosion (with physics as if it was already calculated) at frame 86. (Notably, I animated the `Density` option in the `Physics->Smoke->Flow` panel for the sphere) I looked over my animation panel and probably all of my settings to see whether there was anything related to this, but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I have tested fire in another Blender file. This is specific to this setup somehow.

Comment: Could you post the blend file?

Comment: @someonewithpc. Blend too big for http://pasteall.org, trying to upload with my CloudApp. (It'll be temporarily up for maybe a week or few.)

Comment: I'm having trouble with it. Does anyone know another way to upload my .blend?

Comment: Use dropbox.com, you get 2gb for free